# Shooting in pygame not working

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a code in pygame to shoot bullets but it isn't working as it gives an out of index error. Here is my code. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
while fire ==True:
    print 'FIRE'
    for bullet in bullets[:]:
        nowtime=pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if (nowtime-bullets[3])>1000:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
    if fire and not oldfire:
        bullets.append([int(x_coord),int(y_coord),angle,pygame.time.get_ticks()])
    oldfire=fire
    screen.fill(white)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bx=bullet[0]
        by=bullet[1]
        ba=bullet[2]
        bt=bullet[3]
        rads=-(ba/360)*2*math.pi
        x=int(bx+(blsp*bvel*0.36*math.cos(rads)))
        y=int(by+(blsp*bvel*0.36*math.sin(rads)))
        print x,y,ba,bt
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,green,[x,y],8)
        bullet[0]=x
        bullet[1]=y
pygame.quit()
```

**Update 1**

Here is my entire code which might be helpful. Thanks!

```
import pygame,math
from pygame import *
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)
red = (255,0,0)
arrow=pygame.image.load('plane.png')
explosion=pygame.image.load('explosion.png')
explosion=pygame.transform.scale(explosion,(300,200))
arrow=pygame.transform.scale(arrow,(150,50))
pygame.init()
size=[1100,900]
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
done=False
fire=False
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(1)
x_speed=0
y_speed=0
x_coord=10
y_coord=10
bullets=[]
oldfire=[]
sp=9
angle=0
blsp=1
bvel=30
def pri():
    rotarrow=pygame.transform.rotate(arrow, angle)
    rotrec=rotarrow.get_rect()
    rotrec.center=(x_coord,y_coord)
    screen.blit(rotarrow,rotrec)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
def explode():
    screen.fill([255,255,255])
    screen.blit(explosion,(x_coord-150,700))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()

while done==False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done=True
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            angle=angle+1
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            angle=angle-1
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            sp=18
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            sp=6
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            fire=True
    y_coord += (math.sin(-angle / (180/math.pi)) * sp)
    x_coord += (math.cos(-angle / (180/math.pi)) * sp)
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            sp=9
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            sp=9
    y_coord+=5#gravity
    if x_coord<80:
        x_coord=80

    if x_coord>size[0]-80:
        x_coord=size[0]-80

    if y_coord < 80:
        y_coord=80
    if y_coord>size[0]-80:
        explode()
        break
    screen.fill(white)
    pri()
while fire ==True:
    print 'FIRE'
    for bullet in bullets[:]:
        nowtime=pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if (nowtime-bullets[2])>1000:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
    if fire and not oldfire:
        bullets.append([int(x_coord),int(y_coord),angle,pygame.time.get_ticks()])
    oldfire=fire
    screen.fill(white)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bx=bullet[0]
        by=bullet[1]
        ba=bullet[2]
        bt=bullet[3]
        rads=-(ba/360)*2*math.pi
        x=int(bx+(blsp*bvel*0.36*math.cos(rads)))
        y=int(by+(blsp*bvel*0.36*math.sin(rads)))
        print x,y,ba,bt
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,green,[x,y],8)
        bullet[0]=x
        bullet[1]=y
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code *and* accurately describe the problem.  This includes supplying the full error message and stack trace, the output of any tracing print statements you've used (you did try to debug this yourself before posting, right?), and any other thoughts you have on the operation of the program.

Answer (score 0):

While the specific stack trace would be helpful, your issue probably stems from this line:

```
if (nowtime-bullets[3])>1000:
```

I think you mean to check the fourth parameter of the bullet array (which you have referenced as `bt` later). However, that would be `bullet[3]`, you have `bullets[3]`, which is checking for the fourth bullet. If you don't have that many bullets in the array, it will generate an index error.